# How to re-apply for pages_messaging permission for existing live Facebook messenger bot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a facebook messenger bot, which is in production and has lots of users. Application behind the bot already has approved pages_messaging permission for a year. Few days ago, I've got request from Facebook that permission will be removed in 1 month and if I still need it, I have to re-apply for it.

Clicking the link in the message brings me to the "Request for App Review" page, where on the last step I get:

> You do not have any platforms eligible for review. Please configure a platform on your Settings page. Please visit the Messenger tab to submit for Messenger permissions.

and when I go to "App Review for Messenger", I already have pages_messaging permission granted and there's no way to request it again.

So I'm kinda stuck - I need to apply for the permission that I already have and there's no clear explanation how to do it in such case. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thank you

Comment: Ever thought about going to the actual facebook support?

Comment: @Freddy789 Yes, not only thought but also tried:

a) Developer community forum question unanswered for about 1-week
b) FAQ does not contain relevant information for my case
c) When trying to open "Direct support" question, I get "All support subscriptions have either expired or have no questions remaining" and I could not find the way how to increase this limit, neither in facebook nor in google (still I found others having the same issue)

Personally, I didn't find other options for contacting support and I will be grateful if you can share better ways.

Comment: @Shota were you able to get in contact with Facebook support over this and/or "add" a direct support subscription? We're facing a similar situation with our FB Messenger bot - we're unable to send some messages, but without a clear violation that we could appeal.